# How do default NSG rules allow internet queries on VMs?

Tags: azure, azure-nsg

The default rules of an NSG are as follows.

Inbound:

```
+-----------------------------------+----------+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+------------------+----------+--------+
|               Name                | Priority |     Source IP      | Source Port | Destination IP  | Destination Port | Protocol | Access |
+-----------------------------------+----------+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+------------------+----------+--------+
| ALLOW VNET INBOUND                |    65000 | VIRTUAL_NETWORK    | *           | VIRTUAL_NETWORK | *                | *        | ALLOW  |
| ALLOW AZURE LOAD BALANCER INBOUND |    65001 | AZURE_LOADBALANCER | *           | *               | *                | *        | ALLOW  |
| DENY ALL INBOUND                  |    65500 | *                  | *           | *               | *                | *        | DENY   |
+-----------------------------------+----------+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+------------------+----------+--------+
```

Outbound:

```
+-------------------------+----------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+------------------+----------+--------+
|          Name           | Priority |    Source IP    | Source Port | Destination IP  | Destination Port | Protocol | Access |
+-------------------------+----------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+------------------+----------+--------+
| ALLOW VNET OUTBOUND     |    65000 | VIRTUAL_NETWORK | *           | VIRTUAL_NETWORK | *                | *        | ALLOW  |
| ALLOW INTERNET OUTBOUND |    65001 | *               | *           | INTERNET        | *                | *        | ALLOW  |
| DENY ALL OUTBOUND       |    65500 | *               | *           | *               | *                | *        | DENY   |
+-------------------------+----------+-----------------+-------------+-----------------+------------------+----------+--------+
```

If a VM that is associated with this NSG gets on an internet browser and navigates to a website, how does the website get returned to the VM?

From what I can see, outbound traffic is allowed, but only traffic from a VNET or LB is allowed back in.

Wouldn't the VM send out a HTTP request, which would hit the destination server, which would send the response back to the VM, ultimately get blocked by the NSG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because outbound traffic is allowed - the connection gets established and packets are using already established connection. NSG blocks new connections from being created, doesnt touch existing connections.

Comment: What maintains the list of active connections?

Comment: nsg does, so azure